# Wait for a couple of minutes to check if an URL is responding

Tags: url, ansible, wait, http-response-codes, until-loop

I run a start script using Ansible as below:

```yaml
- name: Start service
  raw: "source ~/.profile; ~/start.sh"
```

Now, I want to keep checking the HTTP status for the services I started above until it is successful — `200`.

Below is how I check for HTTP status `200`, but, I do not know how to keep checking for 2 minutes and report if the URL still does not return `200`.

```yaml
- name: Detect if HTTp response is '200'
  uri:
    url: 'http://example.org/iportal/'
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
    status_code:
      - 200
  register: uri_output
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an [`until`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) loop:

```yaml
- name: Wait until HTTP status is 200
  uri:
    url: 'http://example.org/iportal/'
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
    status_code:
      - 200
  until: uri_output.status == 200
  retries: 24 # Retries for 24 * 5 seconds = 120 seconds = 2 minutes
  delay: 5 # Every 5 seconds
  register: uri_output
```

*Please mind that*: in this case, you might see different timing if your request ends up timing out. The default [`timeout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-timeout) of the `uri` module is 30 seconds.

In this case, you will have 24 retries * 5 seconds delay + 24 retries * 30 seconds until timeout, so, around 14 minutes.
From there on, either adapt the timeout or the number of retries, or a mix of both.